HoughCircles() - openCV 4.10 for Delphi
My first experience with OpenCV 4.10 for Delphi. I'm trying the HoughCircles() function, but I'm confused by the new variable types. How to determine number of circles, circle radius and center? Thank you.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html#autotoc_md669
https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV-Class
HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
                 gray.rows/16,  // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
                 100, 30, 1, 30 // change the last two parameters
            // (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles
    );


with the arguments:

gray: Input image (grayscale).
circles: A vector that stores sets of 3 values:
for each detected circle.
HOUGH_GRADIENT: Define the detection method. Currently this is the only one available in OpenCV.
dp = 1: The inverse ratio of resolution.
min_dist = gray.rows/16: Minimum distance between detected centers.
param_1 = 200: Upper threshold for the internal Canny edge detector.
param_2 = 100*: Threshold for center detection.
min_radius = 0: Minimum radius to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default.
max_radius = 0: Maximum radius to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default.


procedure TForm1.FindCircles(const AMat: TMat);
const
  Param1 = 100;
  Param2 = 30;
  RadiusMin  = 1;
  RadiusMaks = 300;
var
  ImgGray: TMat; // TInputArray
  Circles: Vector<TVec4i>; // TOutputArray, but need 3 values
  Circle:  TVec4i; //array [0..2] of integer;
  CirclesCount: integer;
  Radius:  integer;
  Center:  TPoint;
  i: integer;
begin
  cvtColor(AMat, ImgGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  MedianBlur(ImgGray, ImgGray, 3); 

  try
    // Detect circles and store them in the Circles array
    HoughCircles(ImgGray, Circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, // Error
                      ImgGray.rows/16, Param1, Param2, RadiusMin, RadiusMaks);

    if (not Circles.Empty) // ???
    then begin
      CirclesCount := ???? // how get circles count

      if (CirclesCount > 0)
      then begin
        for i := 0 to CirclesCount - 1 do begin
          Circle := Circles[i];  

          Center := Point(cvRound(Circle[0]), cvRound(Circle[1]));
          Radius := cvRound(Circle[2]);

          cv.OpenCV.Circle(ImgGray, Center, 1, Scalar(0, 100, 100), 3);
          cv.OpenCV.Circle(ImgGray, Center, Radius, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);
        end;
      end;
  finally
    ImgGray.copyTo(AMat);
    ImgGray.release();
  end;
end;


Test for empty with Length(Circles) as you can with any array?

Definitely OpenCV port lacks of data mangling. I set TMat type, used picture from this example page

and found that Mat dimensions are 1x3 - so three circles were detected.
Made rough data extraction:
type
  TSingleArray = array[0..9999] of Single;
  PSingleArray = ^TSingleArray;
var
  AMat, ImgGray: TMat; // TInputArray
  Circles: TMat;
  n, i: integer;
  PFA: PSingleArray;
begin
  AMat := imread('D:\houghcircles2.jpg', IMREAD_COLOR);
  cvtColor(AMat, ImgGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  MedianBlur(ImgGray, ImgGray, 3);
  imwrite('D:\houghcircles21.jpg', ImgGray);
  // Detect circles and store them in the Circles array
  HoughCircles(ImgGray, Circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,  ImgGray.rows/4, 200, 100);
  PFA := PSingleArray(circles.Data);
  n := Circles.cols;
  for i := 0 to n-1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('x: %4.1f y: %4.1f radius %4.2f', [PFA[3*i], PFA[3*i+1], PFA[3*i+2]]));

Result:
x: 135.0 y: 125.0 radius 44.80
x: 89.0 y: 47.0 radius 45.80
x: 43.0 y: 131.0 radius 49.00

